VS 2022 - Performance Profiler - select a different range of time to view the data
I am using the Diagnostic tool to collect CPU Usage data.
When a breakpoint is hit, i enable the CPU Profiling.
At the second breakpoint, it should show me the results, that it shows sometimes but most of the times i get the below message & no results are displayed.
Any idea about why this message comes & how to rectify this?



You could open that filter button and check if all the threads you need are properly selected ,or try to capture the data on a longer interval so the profile can get sufficient data for you.
